# How to store a simple read-only database in the Android app?

Tags: android

I am looking for an elegant solution for the following problem:

The application I am working on connects to some remote device and of course there may occur many different problems with the connection or the remote device. Each problem has its own error code. When the remote device reports an issue, I would like to show a description to the user, not only the error code. The additional requirement is that the description has to be localized.

My current solution is probably the simplest - there is a separate xml file in the resources with strings - the error code as the name of the string and the description as the value.

To find the description I am using the following code:

```
try {
    description = getContext().getResources().getString(getContext().getResources().getIdentifier(item.getErrorId().toUpperCase(), "string", "com.mypackage"));
} catch (NotFoundException e) {
    description = getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.description_not_available);
}
```

I do not like this solution, because it pollutes the strings namespace (there are many possible issues), and it uses exceptions catching.

Is there any better/standard way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you would be aware of possibilities of handeling this in android,
as you can -

1. [Create an sqlite database](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)
2. or, [use an external sqlite database](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)
3. Save them in preferences.

But still I would suggest the method you have used is by far the best for case you have. Or let me know what issues you are facing so that I could suggest something better.

Comment: Yes, I gather that I can use the SQLite DB, however as far I know, Android does not support pre-populated DBs out of the box. I have found some external libraries that can do this, but it makes the solution a bit too complex.

Comment: did you check the second link I provided? it says you can use pre-populated DBs without external libraries. Or we have different ideas of 'external DB'.